# Open interval as an image of the segment

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Find some arbitrary functions $f$ so that there is a segment $[a,b]$ whose image $f([a,b])$ is an open interval.

My question is:

Does it mean the function is either discontinuous on that interval or undefined at all?

For example:

$f(x)=\log_a x$ and $ f([0,b])=log_a(\langle0,b])$,

$$or$$

$g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g([-3,1])=g(\langle 0,1])$
$$or$$
$h(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$ and $h([-2,2])=h([-2,0\rangle\cup\langle0,2])$

Comment: Your function cannot be continuous as the continuous image of a compact set is necessarily compact, and no (nonempty) open interval is compact.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ and $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }\lvert x\rvert<1\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f\bigl([-1,1]\bigr)=(-1,1)$.